# Not able to find the interactive gesture events like igiZoom, igiPan or igiRotate for vcl component in delphi XE7

Tags: windows, delphi, touch, interactive, gestures

I want to use the interactive gesture event for my windows application(for mouse and touch).
 Although **OnGesture(Sender: TObject; const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);**
 event is triggered, while zooming with two finger touch,  I am always getting EventInfo.gestureId is 0. But I am getting the standard gestures. 
Note : I am using Delphi XE7 for development and windows 8.1 touch device for testing.

```
procedure TForm1.GISGesture(Sender: TObject; 
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
begin 
    if (EventInfo.GestureID = igipan) or(EventInfo.GestureID = igiZoom)  then
    begin
      ShowMessage('zoom or pan');
    end;
end;
```

Here EventInfo.GestureID is 0 whenever I tried to zoom with two finger or pan.

Comment: If you're looking for those `igiPan`, `igiZoom` and `igiRotate` constants, add [System.UITypes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.UITypes#Constants) unit to the uses clause. If not, describe what you want, ask a question.

Comment: Sorry  @TLama for my unclear question,I am getting the events for standard gesture but not gettting the interactive gesture, While I am zooming with two finger, Ongesture event is triggered but the  Eventinfo.gesture id is always 0.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Controls.TInteractiveGesture

Comment: You've not spent enough time asking the question. Please edit it (significantly) to explain in detail what you seek to achieve, what you've done, and how it fails. Please don't ask the question in comments.

Comment: Thee edit doesn't contain real code and isn't formatted properly. Please use the help in the edit window to sort out the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On VCL gestures like are igZoom and igRotate are disabled by default so no events are fired for them.

You can enable them through Touch property of your component that should react to these gestures.

[image: Gestures settings in Object Inspector]

Comment: I have tried this without success. Still getting the GestureId = 0.

Comment: @Ashis Then the only other possible cause for this that I can think of would be that your hardware might not have multi-touch capability. Have you tried the existing Samples that ship with Delphi?

Comment: I also thought of this problem and I tried to zoom in and zoom out with using two finger one image using widows picture manager, And this is working fine. But I haven't tried with Existing samples that ship with Delphi. Can you please help me on where I get those samples.

Comment: @Ashis The samples are usually installed at C:\Users\YourUsername\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Samples. You can also find them on the internet at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE8/en/Main_Page

Comment: Yes, you are right @SilverWarior. Everything is correct, the problem was : With my touch device I remotely connected to my development machine and trying to debug(Which is windows 7), so I could not able to catch those events. But now I create the exe and run into my touch device environment and it works fine.

Comment: @Ashis Yes that is limitation of remote connection. So far I haven't seen a program that would allow routing multi-touch controls from one computer to another.

Comment: @Ashis Next time when you are posting question like this you should include that information in it.